# How to get default value expression for java.sql.Timestamp in input control

Tags: datetime, jasper-reports

I need to put default value expression for my datetime input control and it using class = `java.sql.Timestamp`

If using `java.util.Date` it can easily be done like so `DATE(2019,8,28)` but it only returns date.

How can to represent default value expression to have date and time using the class = `java.sql.Timestamp` so that it has the date and time?

It should show the correct date and time on the default input control when the report is executed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You use [`new java.sql.Timestamp(long time)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/sql/Timestamp.html#Timestamp-long-), since the constructor `Timestamp(int year,int month,int date,int hour,int minute,int second,int nano)` is deprecated

In your case if you only like to use the `DATE` function (no time) of jasper-reports the expression would be

```
new java.sql.Timestamp(DATE(2019,8,28).getTime())
```

*the [`getTime()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Date.html#getTime()) returns the milliseconds since January 1, 1970, 00:00:00 GMT needed in constructor*

If you also need to specify time jasper-reports have no function and I would use Java 8  (see below), however if this is not possibile you can use [`Timestamp.valueOf`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/sql/Timestamp.html#valueOf-java.lang.String-) but you need to conform to format `yyyy-[m]m-[d]d hh:mm:ss[.f...]`

```
java.sql.Timestamp.valueOf("2019-01-31 14:12:01")
```

If you have other format you can for example parse your values.

```
new java.sql.Timestamp(new java.text.SimpleDateFormat("yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm").parse("2019/08/29 12:13").getTime())
```

### Java 8

If you like to use the `java.time` package that was introduced in java 8 (it's thread safe, handles more clearly time zones  etc) a similar expression can be used.

```
new java.sql.Timestamp(java.time.LocalDate.of(2019, 08, 28).atTime(0,0).atZone(java.time.ZoneId.systemDefault()).toInstant().toEpochMilli())
```

or if you like to specify time directly in constructor use the [LocaDateTime.of](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalDateTime.html#of-int-java.time.Month-int-int-int-int-)

```
new java.sql.Timestamp(java.time.LocalDateTime.of(2015, 02, 20, 12, 40, 25).atZone(java.time.ZoneId.systemDefault()).toInstant().toEpochMilli())
```

To understand more see the [`java.time` api](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-frame.html)